# How to clear the stack of forms properly in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have an application in VB6 for which I am implementing the Autologout functionality. Whenever the application is in the idle state for some time, the user will be logedout by closing all the forms that user has loaded.
I am using a FormStack and unloading all the forms that has been loaded. Inorder to close the forms in a proper way we are using SendKeys ESC and the form will unload with ESC key.

It is working fine in most of the cases, but the problem is if there is something like Keyboard, then with the ESC key the keyboard is getting unloaded, but once all the forms are unloaded, the code next to Keyboard is getting executed which has a reference to forms control and loading the form.

I can do the reference checks, but this functionality is implemented in many places, and it takes time to check everywhere.

I also thought to wait for some time around 500 ms to close every form, but felt it is not good to rely on timers.

Could anyone suggest a better idea to unload all the forms smoothly.

Comment: Why are you not just `unload theform` in a `for each theform in forms`?

Comment: Hi Alex, Many thanks for your responce.

Comment: Hi Alex, Many thanks for your responce. Initially I did unload the forms itself. But at that time I got the same issue with the referencing the forms elements in many places. To getrid of tha I thought to close the form smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

i used to do
    dim i as integer

```
for i = forms.count -1 to 0 step -1
 unload forms(i)
next
```

also you can create a interface an implement that in the form

```
IDispose

 sub Close()



dim miclazz as IDispose

form each miclazz in forms
  miclazz.Close()
next
```

Comment: Why would creating a new interface with a Close() method help in this situation? The Close() method will still have to be something like: Unload Me.

Comment: just for order, if you work with an pattern how MVP in your code have one piece dynamic of code

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw you could check for the interface and call it if present or call unload if not present. That would allow you to unload most forms and customise ones that caused a problem